# Pasting a linked chart from Excel into Powerpoint using a relative spreadsheet

Tags: excel, charts, hyperlink, powerpoint-2016

Each month I have to update a set of Powerpoint slides with the most recent data. Each slide has a chart. The data lives in an Excel file as do the charts. There are two business requirements:

- I need to paste the chart as linked so that other users can access the underlying data
- For each month there has to be a separate folder. I copy in the previous month's slides and Excel file.

Ideally, I would just have to update the data in the Excel file and then open the Powerpoint slides to have them update. The issue is that the charts are linked to the previous month's Excel file.

Is there a way to indicate to Powerpoint to use the Excel file in the same directory? We use version 2016 of the Office products.

Answer (score 0):

On the PPT FAQ site that I maintain, there's a VBA macro that will help with this:

https://www.rdpslides.com/pptfaq/FAQ00759_Search_-_Replace_to_change_OLE_link_paths.htm

Rather than hard-coding the paths, you could substitute ActivePresentation.Path & "" to make it change the OLE links to the same file name but in the same folder as the current presentation.